# Pipe character causes "unexpected token" error in Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to recreate the HTML design of an existing login form for use in an MVC4 program. Most of this is fine, however when I try to enter a pipe character ( | ) between two elements, it throws an error "unexpected token". You can see it there at the bottom, after the button and before the anchor. Any ideas why this is an error? Is there a way to fix it? (Other than removing the pipe character?)

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "AccountController", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-login form-wrapper form-narrow" }))
    { 
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <h3 class="title-divider"><span>Login</span> <small>Not signed up? @Html.ActionLink("Sign Up Here.", "Register")</small></h3>

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "input-block-level" } )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "input-block-level" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Log in" >Sign in</button>
    | <a href="#">Forgotten Password?</a>
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put it inside `<text>` tags or use the `@:` operator

```
<text>|</text>
```

or

```
@:|
```

Inside the using statement, you are actually in a razor code block, so anything *not* inside an html tag or preceded by the @: operator will be read as server code.